# Asynchronous loading image with request

Tags: swift, asynchronous, uicollectionview

I have an api in which I get a link for request. In order to get a picture, I need to make a request in response to which I receive image data. How can I make getting asynchronous images? I find a lot of libraries and videos in youtube where this make with image link. But how i can do it in my case?

```
let token_type = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "token_type")
let access_token = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "access_token")

let headers:HTTPHeaders? = ["Authorization":  "\(token_type ?? "") \(access_token ?? "")"]

            Alamofire.request(cellInfo.imageLink ?? "", method: .get, headers: headers).responseImage { response in

                if let image = response.result.value {
                    cell.firstTypeImageView.image = image
                }
            }
```

Comment: i want use alamofire. But i can't understand how i can do it with link on request  for image data without image url.

Comment: First i get api in which is located url. I need make request on this url with header and  in response i get image data.

Comment: I add my request for get image data. But this is not good work, image dublicate each other and don't download asynchronously.

Comment: Re async vs non-async, the above is, most certainly, running asynchronously, so I suspect some other problem. E.g. if your images are much larger than the image view in which you’re presenting them, there are solutions for preventing the “stuttering” UI that can happen in this scenario. Re “duplicate” images that can appear when you have cells being reused, but the answer below should address that problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your example is that if the cell is reused by the time the image is retrieved, you’ll be updating the wrong row with this image. If updating the image view, it’s better to use the `UIImageView` [extension](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage#uiimageview-extension). You enjoy several benefits with table view cells when you do this because it will automatically cancel the prior request for this cell. This means that:

- It eliminates the problem of scrolling quickly having the image view in a reused cell flickering as images are retrieved for rows in the table.
- It also means that you don’t have to worry about the current cell getting backlogged behind requests for cells that are no longer visible.

So, you might do something like:

```
if let imageLink = cellInfo.imageLink, let url = URL(string: imageLink) { 
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let authValue = "\(token_type ?? "") \(access_token ?? "")"
    request.setValue(authValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    cell.firstTypeImageView.af_setImage(withURLRequest: request)
}
```

Or maybe you have a placeholder image, e.g. `blank.png`, then you’d do:

```
cell.firstTypeImageView.af_setImage(withURLRequest: request, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "blank"))
```

---

Note, if your images are much larger than the image view in which you’re presenting them, you can see some stuttering in the tableview as the OS struggles to deal with such large assets. In that scenario, you can add a resizing filter:

```
let filter = AspectScaledToFillSizeFilter(size: cell.firstTypeImageView.frame.size)                 // or use whatever size appropriate
cell.firstTypeImageView.af_setImage(withURLRequest: request, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "blank"), filter: filter)
```